# ChartJS - adding scroll to horizontal legend in Line chart

Tags: chart.js

I am creating project with ChartJs, and I am fetching real time data from the server. Each second, I add extra data point. After some time, there is just too many points on the graph, to the point that you cannot see anything. I would like to know, if there is a way to scroll through the x-variables, and always have set distance between the points? As of know, the distance between points is shrinking, making the graph not readable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know, if there is a way to scroll through the
>   x-variables,

You can use `.removeData( )` to remove the (current) first set of points. This would keep only the same number of (latest) points visible on the graph.

> ...and always have set distance between the points?

Unless you remove points maintain a set distance while adding points would cause the graph width to increase - which is usually not what you want to do.